# Viewing the content of a file without extension in the URL

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

Using Apache and Centos 7, I have put two specific files in `/var/www/html` as below

```
[root@sn acme-challenge]# pwd
/var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
[root@sn acme-challenge]# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 88 Dec 21 12:19 8KyeoB4HPzOPR6Et9uBPWoldME6LGIBV3ps
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  2 Dec 21 12:20 test.txt
[root@sn acme-challenge]# cat 8KyeoB4HPzOPR6Et9uBPWoldME6LGIBV3ps
8KyeoB4HPzOPR6Et9uBPWoldME6LGIBV3ps.QTHp9d8EEr94A5QohL1LAlh51l9Wsy4ET1jo
[root@sn acme-challenge]# cat test.txt
uu
```

When I enter `https://somewhere.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt`, the content of the file is shown which is `uu`.

However, when I enter `https://somewhere.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/8KyeoB4HPzOPR6Et9uBPWoldME6LGIBV3ps`, it is redirected to the main site which is `https://somewhere.com`.

The content of `/var/www/html/.htaccess` is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

<Files CHANGELOG.txt>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files INSTALL.txt>
deny from all
</Files>
<Files UPDATE.txt>
deny from all
</Files>



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/classes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/e500\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/captcha\.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

How can I fix that so that I can view the content of `8KyeoB4HPzOPR6Et9uBPWoldME6LGIBV3ps`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
```

The **/[^.]*** is matching files with no extension.
Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw)$  [NC]
```

Tested it on my server, seems to make the difference.