# Unauthorized error when trying to get a ssl certificate with certbot

Tags: ssl, security, certificate, deployment, backend

I recently bought a domain, hosting and a Ubuntu 22.04 vps, all on godaddy.
The domain and hosting work, I can  access the site by typing the url in.
But when I try to get a ssl certificate with certbot, this is what I get:

```
root@35:~# sudo certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
We recommend selecting either all domains, or all domains in a VirtualHost/server block.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: cihanbatasul.com
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate numbers separated by commas and/or spaces, or leave input
blank to select all options shown (Enter 'c' to cancel): 1
Requesting a certificate for cihanbatasul.com

Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: apache). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: cihanbatasul.com
  Type:   unauthorized
  Detail: 92.205.171.180: Invalid response from http://cihanbatasul.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/gGguqH44EsxtOmUeswWsjDx9xtSR70HrJzwEBjXuaZQ: 404

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to verify the temporary Apache configuration changes made by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains point to this Apache server and that it is accessible from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

My 000-default.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The conf file for my domain named cihanbatasul.com.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName cihanbatasul.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/
        <Location "/.well-known/acme-challenge/">
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
                ForceType text/plain
                RedirectMatch 404 "^(?!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]{43}$)"
        </Location>

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I don't know if I specified the DocumentRoot correctly. I used the folder structure of my godaddy document tree:
[Link to folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AEjq.png)

I also don't have the acme files and don't know where to find them or make them available.
I would appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unauthorized error when requesting ssl certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/1152352/unauthorized-error-when-requesting-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Please don't repost questions when you don't get answers. That will not lead to better answers.

Comment: So what do I do when I get no answer? It's been 4 days so I tought I might try again.

Comment: If noone answers, noone answers. Re-posting will *not* work. Reading [*How to ask a good question*](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) may be worth it. Edit your question to update it.

Comment: Do create `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` in your document root. Create a sample file `foo.txt` in there with some content and try accessing it in a browser by visiting `http://cihanbatasul.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/foo.txt`. Also create a file called `bar` but without any extension, then try to visit that: `http://cihanbatasul.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/bar`. If it fails, your Apache server is configured not to serve files without an extension. See the answer to this to fix it: https://serverfault.com/questions/946257/viewing-the-content-of-a-file-without-extension-in-the-url

Answer (score 0):

Your server block is incorrect, for letsencrypt it should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydom.tld

  Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/
  <Directory "/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/">
      Options None
      AllowOverride None
      ForceType text/plain
      RedirectMatch 404 "^(?!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]{43}$)"
  </Directory>

  # ... remaining configuration
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure the ssl module for apache is enabled

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Regarding the document root, best practice is to let it look like this

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Let's Encrypt challenge location
    Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /var/www/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/

    <Location "/.well-known/acme-challenge/">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        ForceType text/plain
        RedirectMatch 404 "^(?!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]{43}$)"
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This should be stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomain.conf`

Make sure to enable this vhost and remove the rest which you created previously

Comment: That didn't work, I still get the same issue. That's the configuration that you recommend for the config file of the domain that I want to get the certificate for right? I have default config and made one for the domain. Also, is the DocumentRoot right like this: ```         DocumentRoot /home/xigo0kih99bf/public_html```? I'm using the path of my hosting file structure but I don't know if that is the way to do it.

Comment: For some extra information please do a test using https://letsdebug.net/. You need to put the config in one place

Comment: I have edited my answer with the best practice for apache

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made the changes but still get the same error. Do I leave the 000-default.conf file as it is or do I make changes to it? I also created the acme directory inside the ```var/www/html``` directory but that also didn't help. I will edit my initial to the current state of my conf file.

Comment: Let's continue in the chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151200/letsencrypt-certbot-apache

Comment: Thank you, I joined!